# Are mathematical questions acceptable on SO?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, migrated-questions

A few weeks ago I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132587/polygons-generated-by-a-set-of-segments) on math.stackexchange:

I'm still looking for the name of the problem. This is a computational geometry because I suspect that it has been solved. One the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_geometry) listing the classical computatational geometry problems, I did not find an exact match for what I'm looking for.

Should I reformulate the question? Embed an image (I could not join an image IIRC because I did not have enough rep) ? Ask the question where programmers could see it (instead of mathematicians) ?

Comment: Smells like "send me the algorithmz"...not for SO, no.

Comment: You could start by considering Ross Millikan's comment: are you in fact looking for all **lattice squares** within a region, or all **polygons** (of which there are infinitely many)? "the set of non overlapping polygons that we intuitively see" is not a productive definition whether you are talking about mathematics or algorithms.

Comment: I just want to find the name of the problem, or if it is a restriction of another problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For computer science questions, including algorithm questions, I recommend asking on **[Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)**. (I am a moderator there.) I don't know anything about computational geometry, but your question looks reasonable, and there are competent people who visit CS.SE. While my understanding is that all algorithm questions are considered on-topic on Math.SE, they tend to be outliers: you have the wrong target audience.

I believe that Math.SE's policy allows migrating computer science questions when they are unanswered and the asker agrees, so you should flag your question for **migration** to CS.SE. Please do not repost the question, as having the question in multiple places makes answers harder to find. Since you have only 1 reputation on Math.SE, you won't be able to flag; if you agree to the migration, someone else (e.g. me) can flag it for you.

Algorithm questions are allowed by Stack Overflow's [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), but they tend to get a poor reception: if you haven't committed to a programming language, SO is probably the wrong place.

Comment: I agree with your proposition to migrate it to CS.SE. I just created an image to illustrate what I'm talking about, but I can't post it because of my low rep.

Answer (score 3):

If mathematical question's/ algorithm's implementation is needs to be done in any programming language(which are allowed to discuss on SO). And you are facing problems in it.

ie. `I have implemented algorithm in language, it should do this but it does this. I tried already this and that, but it still shows that odd behavior.` type questions are fine on SO.

**Otherwise mathematical questions are not allowed on SO.**

Comment: Do not forget that "how could I implement this algorithm in language" and "how do I write algorithm in language" are *not* good questions.

Comment: @UristMcBobby: Yeah. I mean if you are facing problem in implementing logic or any error messages. Then it allowed, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, sure, "I have implemented algorithm in language, it should do this but it does this. I tried already this and that, but it still shows that odd behavior." type questions are fine for the most part.